# Thread, Wait, Notify, Sleep in Java

Tags: java, sleep, wait, notify, jprogressbar

I am developing/developed a desktop application, where the button has actionlistener and to do lot of background task, I didnt use the thread, wait, notify or sleep before. I am just confused which one to learn and which one to use otherwise when i click the button, the JFrame just freezes.

1) Could someone suggest me what to use and easier?

2) I am using jprogress bar with setvalue(n) method, but I would like to replace the n automatically with the time taken to load, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
You need to move your code running when you click your button into a new thread. Something like this will work:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    public Worker() {
        t = new Thread(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do stuff here
    }
    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Then when you click your button in your JFrame:

```
Worker w = new Worker();
w.start();
```

2) You can call `setProgress()` with any `int` (eg, at the start get current time, at the end get current time, time taken = end-start) you want. Just make sure you have used `setMaximum()` too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swing for GUI you should use "SwingWorker" class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html